# Why does useLazyFetch composable returns null data?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to learn how to use the data fetching composables in Nuxt3. **For some reason, I get a "loading" text in place of where the username should be:**

[image]

My expected output is supposed to be something like:

[image]

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-grcyfr?file=components/PostCard.vue

Here's my composable code:
`useUser`:

```
export default function (id) {
  const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  const { pending: pendingUsers, data: users } = useLazyFetch(
    `${baseURL}/users`
  );
  const { pending: pendingUser, data: user } = useLazyFetch(
    `${baseURL}/users/${id}`
  );

  return {
    pendingUsers,
    users,
    pendingUser,
    user,
  };
}
```

And the component where I want to use it is here:
`PostCard.vue`:

```
<template>
  <article class="rounded border overflow-hidden">
    ...snip...
      <footer class="mt-6 flex items-center">
        <PostAvatar :post="post" />
        <div class="ml-3">
          <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
            <a href="#" class="hover:underline">
              {{ pendingUser ? 'Loading...' : user.name }} /////<---- HERE!
            </a>
          </p>
          <div class="flex space-x-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
            <!-- <time :datetime="post.datetime">
              {{ post.date }}
            </time> -->
            mar 4, 2019
            <span aria-hidden="true">&middot;</span>
            <span>misc</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    ...snip...
  </article>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  post: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({}),
  },
});
const { pendingUser, user } = useUser(props.post.userId);
</script>
```

Anyone know why the username is not loading? If I `console.log(pendingUser.value, user.value)` I get `true null`

Comment: Tried to add some `async/await` for the composante + an await when called?

Comment: I tried different things. I also tried: `const { pendingUser, user } = await useUser(props.post.userId);` and did not help. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: The only thing that worked was changing the package.json nuxt version as you mentioned prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Not sure if it's an actual current issue but downgrading `nuxt` to `3.0.0-rc.1` fixed the issue.

---

Given this composable

`/composables/useUser.js`

```js
export default (id) => {
  const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  const { pending: pendingUser, data: user } = useLazyFetch(
    `${baseURL}/users/${id}`
  );
  return {
    pendingUser,
    user,
  };
}
```

And this view

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<script setup>
const { pendingUser, user } = useUser(2);

watch(user, (newUser) => {
  console.log('newUser', newUser);
  user.value = newUser;
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>pending? {{ pendingUser }}</div>
    <pre>{{ pendingUser ? 'loading' : user }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

You should have something working.

The usage of `watch` may be needed (not sure) as explained in [the documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-lazy-fetch#example) because `useLazyFetch` is async and non-blocking.

Comment: no luck. Still same issue. I've updated my code to yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-grcyfr?file=composables/useUser.js

Comment: @redshift not sure what is the exact issue but here is a working [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt-starter-xi3an2). The main fix was to downgrade to `3.0.0-rc.1`. The `async/await` may not be the main culprit.

Comment: that worked! I also just changed it to use `npm:nuxt3@latest` .

Comment: @redshift you should use `nuxt` rather than `nuxt3`.

Comment: docs say: `npm:nuxt3@latest` : https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/edge-channel . Confirm?

Comment: @redshift no need to be on the edge channel if the RC is available: https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/nuxt3-rc/#vite--webpack